# How to send an app to a friend?

Tags: store, sharing

How do I share an app? I'd like to share an app with my friend. Is it possible? Just want to send him a link to the store directly from my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the app installed on your phone, just find it in the app list, long-press on it and select "share", then choose how you want to share it (email, SMS, Facebook, OneNote and so on).

If you don't have the app installed, open Store and find it there. If it's a free app, then tap the "share" button at the bottom. If it's a paid app, then expand the app bar (tap the "..." icon at the bottom") and select "share" from there.

Answer (score -3):

Open play store on your phone, open the particular app (you want to share the link of ) , as you open at the bottom you will see two option install/view and share click on share you will get options like google mail , Yahoo mail, facebook and many others choose the one through which you want to share the link.

Comment: Play Store, @NishaPriya?

Comment: Which phone are you using ?

Comment: This SE is for Windows Phone only if you haven't noticed yet, @NishaPriya

Comment: I am not talking about the OS, I am talking about phone ( nokia , HTC etc ). Anyways play store is where you download apps from, As indrek mentioned the 'STORE' .

Comment: Play Store is an app store for Android, @NishaPriya. Windows Phone is not Android.

Comment: Okay my bad by mistake I have referred to play store but that is quite understood what I meant was the STORE (for WP), here we all are talking about WP not Android and both are two very different things.